# How to set the font in Sparx Enterprise Architect 8 Script editor

Tags: fonts, ide, enterprise-architect

Does anyone know whether the font on the script editor in Sparx Enterprise Architect can be changed - is there a setting dialog for this somewhere?

**EDIT:** Running EA under Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but I believe it is global for all code editors in EA.

In Enterprise Architect, go to Tools -> Options -> Source Code Engineering -> Code Editors.

Click the Syntax Highlighting Options [...] button.

Click (Global) and you will see the Default properties on the right hand side. By default these are set to Monospace, 10pt. You can then click to change.

I hope this helps!

TomO

Comment: Just a note, this process was done with EA 9.3. I am assuming it would be the same for EA8.

Comment: Certainy works fine in EA 9 :)

Answer (score 0):

In EA12.1, one has to pick this in the Dark or Light theme as Default doesn't have the option.